# How to add a base url to generated elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I have a page where I want to display content from a website inside my app. I have a parser which in this case grab the element from their site and into mine. But I have this problems, the links serverside are like `campaign.aspx?wfege`, when a users clicks it, I want to add a `http://example.com/` before so the link will result in looking like `http://example.com/campaign.aspx?wfege`. It this possible in javascript? If so, how? Please look at my fiddle, it's fully working and is an exact copy of my site.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4vdck/

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in your HTML.

You need to add the base tag with the appropriate href, like this

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">
....
....
</head>
<body>
<a href="campaign.aspx?wfege">ClickHere</a> <!-- Because of the base tag this href will lead you to http://example.com/campaign.aspx?wfege -->
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This resulted in some files, like javascript which I had locally, to be on the server-side. Luckily I have access to the server-side in this case. Cheers!